# Is there an Autodesk Forge API that targets .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, autodesk-forge

We have a .Net Core app that targets .Net Core 1.1. We would like to consume the Autodesk Forge API, but since that API targets the .Net Framework (full framework), that would require our app to also target the .Net Framework instead of .Net Core. Is there an Autodesk Forge API that targets .Net Core?

Comment: you are not consuming the API Autodesk Forge API, if you were that would mean that Autodesk Forge API could be written in whatever language and version frameworks. You are referencing Autodesk Forge API libraries is what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

Forge is a REST API, that means it doesn't target any specific .Net version. You can just use the library of your choice to perform REST requests and parse JSON responses, we also have a .Net SDK that wraps those requests and formats the responses. Take a look at the [.Net QuickStart](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/quickstarts/v1/csharp/) and our [.Net samples on github](https://github.com/Autodesk-forge).